# Displacement of Gaussian point after structure simulation

Tags: structural-analysis, simulation, deformation

When we did the simulation, we would get deformation and got each nodes displacement.

In physics, it shows the trajectory of a system of particles of the objects.

Is it the same as the displacement of the Gaussian point? Does displacement of the Gaussian point (obtained from the Subtraction from two phases gaussian point) also mean the trajectory of a system of particles of the objects?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this an FEA simulation?

Comment: If so, then yes, I think you can interpolate displacement to any point in an element (not only Gaussian points) and that sequence of displacements will follow the path of a particle.

Comment: @user1318499 Yes, it is fea simulation

Comment: @user1318499 What I am afraid is the Gaussian points is generated by current configuration, not based on history configuration.